# Get value from URL into JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, url

I have a JSP from where I am sending parameters to another page.  But the other page is accepting the parameters. I don't know the reason.

How to get value from URL into JSP?

The URL is -

```
/ColdStorage/ajaxservlet?occid%20=%203
```

And the JSP which should accept the parameters is -

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String sql = "";
    PreparedStatement prest ;
    ResultSet rs;
     HttpSession session = null;
    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ColdStorage?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "root");
        System.out.println("entering ajaxservlet");
        String occid = (String) request.getParameter("occid");
        System.out.println("occid = "+occid);
        String resid = (String) request.getParameter("resid");
        System.out.println("resid = "+resid);
        String agrnoid = (String) request.getAttribute("agrno");
        System.out.println("agrnoid = "+agrnoid);

        List<AcceptBean> list1 = new ArrayList<AcceptBean>();
       // List<AcceptBean> list3 = new ArrayList<AcceptBean>();

        sql = "select om.OccId,om.FirstName,om.LastName,om.Village,om.SonOf,om.District, rd.ResId,rd.`Date`,"
                + "rd.Weight,rd.Bags,rd.Rate,rd.Amount,rd.advamount,am.agrno,am.lotno,am.`agreeDate`,am.reservid,"
                + "am.weight,am.bags,am.rate,am.amt,am.advamt from OccupantMaster om left outer join user_resdet ud on "
                + "om.OccId = ud.occ_det left outer join ReservationDetails rd on ud.res_det = rd.ResId left outer join "
                + "AgreementMaster am on rd.ResId = am.reservid where occid = ?  ";
        System.out.println("sql = "+sql);
        prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prest.setString(1, occid);
        rs = prest.executeQuery();
        String agreereservid = "";
        String Date = "";
        String Weight = "";
        String Rate = "";
        String Bags = "";
        String Amount = "";
        String Advance = "";
        String regisamount = "";
        String regisadvance = "";
        String Lotno = "";
```

Comment: any errors you would like to share with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 2 extra spaces in you url:

```
occid%20=%203
sould be:
occid=3
```

Or when you look for the get parameter you should look for "occid "

Comment: @Divyang then approve his answer